# What is the complexity of the LU factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-science

Some sources say it is $O(n^3)$, others that it is $n^3/3+O(n^2)$ and on the stackexchange it is $2/3n^3$. I am not very good with the big O notation, can someone explain which answer is the most precise?

Comment: In Big O notation, all are the same, namely $O(n^3)$. Note: Big O notation is not about precision.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation) helpful. But to answer your question, all the complexities you mentioned, in the big-oh notation are the same. However, wikipedia says LU factorization takes the same time as matrix multiplication.

Comment: The $O(n^3)$ estimate is probably the one applicable to most algorithms for LU factorization. The algorithms may differ in the implicit constant, and expressions such as $n^3/3 + O(n^2)$ are going to provide more information about the performance of a particular algorithm. But these also require a more precise definition of what exactly is measured: execution time, number of arithmetic operations, etc.

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia page also lists certain algorithms with theoretical complexity of $O(n^a)$ for values of $2 \lt a \lt 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix operations tend to cast most computation in terms of a Fused Multiply-Add (FMA).  Some consider this to count as one floating point operation.  Others count the multiply and add separately.

If you count FMAs, then the cost of an LU factorization is approximately $1/3 n^3$.  If you count multiplies and adds separately, then the cost is $1/3 n^3$ multiplies and $1/3 n^3$ adds, and hence you end up with $2/3 n^3$ floating point operations (flops).

If Wikipedia says the count is the same as matrix multiplication, then Wikipedia is wrong.